# Bash on cygwin: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, cygwin

```
commonMongo=s:/programs/mongodb/
dbpath=$commonMongo"data/"
logFile=$commonMongo"log.txt"
mongoProg=s:/programs/mongodb/mongodb/
mongoBin=$mongoProg"bin/"
mongod=$mongoBin"mongod.exe"
a=$1
if [ "$a" == "start" ];then
    "${mongod} --logpath ${logFile} --logappend --dbpath ${dbpath} &"
elif [ "$a" == "repair" ];then
    "${mongod} --dbpath ${dbpath} --repair"
else
    echo "Incorrect usage"
fi
```

./init.sh: line 11: s:/programs/mongodb/mongodb/bin/mongod.exe --dbpath s:/programs/mongodb/data/ --repair: No such file or directory

Calling the printed command works fine:

s:/programs/mongodb/mongodb/bin/mongod.exe --dbpath s:/programs/mongodb/data/ --repair

Comment: Fixed by not wrapping the command in double quotes.

Comment: You should still wrap individual variables `"${mongod}"' & '"${logFIle}"' if they can contain spaces, but yes, the whole line in one set of quotes would cause the error you saw

Answer (score 8):

Cygwin will actually do  magic for you if you put your DOS paths in quotes, for example

```
cd "C:\Program Files\"
```

Answer (score 5):

Cygwin does not recognize Windows drive letters such as `s:`, use `/cygdrive/s` instead.  Your cygwin command should look like this:

```
/cygdrive/s/programs/mongodb/mongodb/bin/mongod.exe --dbpath s:/programs/mongodb/data/ --repair
```

Notice that the path like parameters you pass to the executable are in windows format as `mongod.exe` is not a Cygwin binary.

To make it easier, you could add `mongod.exe` your path, then you do not need to specify the directory it is in.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this, but it is not what caused the problem.